# pandas sort_index documentation

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, documentation

the [documentation](http:///https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for DataFrame.sort_index is:

*DataFrame.sort_index(self, axis=0, level=None, ascending=True, inplace=False, kind='quicksort', na_position='last', sort_remaining=True, by=None)*

but I can not find any information on using the last argument (by= ). [I understand that if no argument "by" is given, the default will be None.] Anyone know what this argument is for and how to use? I find this type of incomplete documentation frustrating...especially since most clarifications are only "by example" and usually only cover basic uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per source code...

> "if by is not None:
>
> warnings.warn(
>
> "by argument to sort_index is deprecated, "
>
> "please use .sort_values(by=...)"